# Can sync 2 GitHub accounts together? Enterprise to personal?

Tags: github

I have a GitHub Enterprise account from school and I have a personal GitHub account. Throughout my course I have been uploading all of my projects to the enterprise account and although I am told I would have "lifetime" access to said enterprise account, I would still like my work to be attached to my personal account.

Is there a way I could link or sync both of my accounts together? Or a way if I push a repo to my enterprise account it will also push to my personal account at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can push your repo's to multiple GitHub accounts. When you first pull from an account, you have access to said account until further notice, even after you exit your terminal. All you need to do is to push your files to the "main" branch of each GitHub account.

For example. My schools repo main branch is not called "main" it is called "master." So after all the commits I would just `git push origin master` . This will push it to school. My personal account however is named main. So right after I push to my school I can just `git push origin main` and it will push it to my personal. Using these two back to back works just fine and it does not matter which one you use first.